# How to exclude array with ids from ElasticSearch results set?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Rails with ElasticSearch. As mapper I'm using https://github.com/karmi/retire .

I have model `Exercise`

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  mapping do
    # ....
  end

  def self.search(params)
    archived_exercise_ids = [1,2,3,4]
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do
      # ES documents have attribute _id

    end
  end
end
```

I have set of ids for exercises which are already archived, let's say:

```
archived_exercise_ids = [1,2,3,4]
```

How I can write search method which won't take into consideration in the results exercises with `id` included in `archived_exercise_ids`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of

```
tire.search(...) do
  query do
    filtered do
      query {all}
      filter :not, {:ids => {:type => :exercise, :values => archived_exercise_ids}}
    end
  end
end
```

You could also use a [terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) filter rather than an [ids](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-filter.html) filter - the latter is special in that it uses the internal elasticsearch _id so it doesn't matter whether _id is indexed

Personally I would be inclined to do neither of these. Instead index the archived attribute and filter on that attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have archived attribute, it's dependent on the context so it would be hard to make it generic for all cases.